# getting error when I install ros-kinetic-rosbridge-suite on ubuntu 16

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone please suggest me?

```
:~$ echo $ROS_DISTRO
kinetic
:~$ sudo apt install ros-kinetic-rosbridge-suite
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-rosbridge-suite
```

---

Edit: The output:

```
:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324612/getting-error-when-i-install-ros-kinetic-rosbridge-suite-on-ubuntu-16/) by [amart](https://answers.ros.org/users/42002/amart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-06-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-04**:
Can you install other ROS pkgs using `apt`? What is the output of `uname -a`? Have you ran `sudo apt update` recently?

**Comment by [amart](https://answers.ros.org/users/42002/amart/) on 2019-06-06**:
i've run sudo apt update. I can't install any ros package.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-06**:
If you can't install any ROS packages then I would guess you haven't setup your system correctly.

Which installation guides (if any) did you follow?

What is the output of

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Edit: The output:

> ```
> :~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
> ```

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main
```

The problem most likely is that you've configured your system to ask the ROS package repositories for Ubuntu Precise (ie: `14.04`) while you are actually running Ubuntu Xenial (`16.04`) -- or at least according to your question title.

I'm not sure how that happened, but you should be able to correct this situation using the following command:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

Note that this will override whatever you have now in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`.

Did you follow the [installation tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu) for ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu Xenial?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amart](https://answers.ros.org/users/42002/amart/) on 2019-06-06**:
Yes I followed http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu for Ros Kinetic on Ubuntu Xenial.
After I run this comment

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

The output has overridden which resulted is :

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main
```

But cannot install rosbridge package yet. Any other suggestion please?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-06**:
Did you run `sudo apt-get update` before trying to install again?

**Comment by [amart](https://answers.ros.org/users/42002/amart/) on 2019-06-06**:
After running sudo apt-get update and try to install again, now it perfectly worked. Thank a lot you saved my time.

**Comment by [amart](https://answers.ros.org/users/42002/amart/) on 2019-06-06**:
Sure. Done sir